# Pipe not firing when target value is null

Tags: angular

I have a simple pipe that highlights text on the fly when a user enters text into a text input.

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'highlight'
})
export class HighlightSearchPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

  transform(value: string, args: string): any {
    console.log('pipe fired');
    if (args === null || args === '') { return value; }
    const index = value.toLowerCase().indexOf(args.toLowerCase());
    if (index === -1) { return value; }
    const str = value.substr(index, args.length);
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value.replace(str, '<mark>' + str + '</mark>'));
  }
}
```

Then I implement it like this for example:

```
<input (input)="searchString = $event.target.value">

<span [innerHTML]="somevalue | highlight: searchString"></span>
```

It works great except when I delete the text within the input, it fails to fire off the pipe, so it will remain the same way it was the last time the pipe was called. I have verified this with the `console.log()` that I put within the pipe.

It seems that when the value recieved is `null` that angular does not fire the pipe. I have tried some workarounds to fire a space `' '` instead of null or an empty string, but that seems hacky.

Comment: have you tried changing the transform ``transform(value: string, args: string): any {`` to allow for a null?

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is here

```
if (args === null || args === '') { return value; }
const index = value.toLowerCase().indexOf(args.toLowerCase());
if (index === -1) { return value; }
```

Html must be sanitized before its bound to the page and the raw string value is being returned in these two cases. I would expect angular to throw an exception of some kind, but maybe its being swallowed somewhere.

Try this:

```
if (args === null || args === '') { return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(''); }
const index = value.toLowerCase().indexOf(args.toLowerCase());
if (index === -1) { return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value); }
```